# ashx handler, access HttpContext.Current inside void

Tags: c#, stream, ashx, mjpeg, aforge

i've changed this question dramaticlly but here it goes. I'm reading a mjpeg stream from an IP cam which all goes fine. But now on every frame which I receive (See stream_NewFrame) I want to push this image to the client. But I cannot seem to figure out how to access the HttpContext.Current cause it always null inside that function. Does anyone know how to access the HttpContext context just like I can do inside the ProcessRequest function? I'm missing something obvious here I guess but I can't figure out what! Thank you for your time.

```
  public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        //Get parameter
        string Url = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
        string Username = context.Request.QueryString["username"];
        string Password = context.Request.QueryString["password"];

        //Set cache 
        HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "multipart/x-mixed-replace";

        // create MJPEG video source
        MJPEGStream stream = new MJPEGStream(string.Format("{0}/video.cgi?user={1}&pwd={2}", Url, Username, Password));
        stream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(stream_NewFrame);
        stream.Start();

    }


    private void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Image img = eventArgs.Frame;
        byte[] b = GetImageBytes(eventArgs.Frame);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just save the `HttpContext` away sometwhere so it's accessible from the `stream_NewFrame` method? I would suggest using a member variable in your class.

If you'd like to encapsulate it more than that, create a separate class that you feed the `HttpContext` into, and put the `stream_NewFrame` method in that class instead. Something like:

```
class Processor

      private HttpContext _context;

      public Processor(HttpContext context) {
           _context = context;
      }

      public void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
      {
          Image img = eventArgs.Frame;
          byte[] b = GetImageBytes(eventArgs.Frame);
          HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
      }
}
```

and then in your `ProcessRequest`, you do like this:

public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{

    //Get parameter
    string Url = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
    string Username = context.Request.QueryString["username"];
    string Password = context.Request.QueryString["password"];

    //Set cache 
    HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    Response.Expires = 0;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "multipart/x-mixed-replace";

    // create processor
    Processor p = new Processor(context);    

    // create MJPEG video source
    MJPEGStream stream = new MJPEGStream(string.Format("{0}/video.cgi?user={1}&pwd={2}", Url, Username, Password));
    stream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(p.stream_NewFrame);
    stream.Start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

MJPEGStream creates a background thread that it operates on. HTTPContext.Current is a thread-local variable, which means that the background thread (which is the thread that is calling the `stream_newFrame` callback function) is on a different thread, so it doesn't have the same `HTTPContext` (in fact it has none). You'll need to provide it some other way. The idea of creating a Processor object to hold the reference like Erik suggested should work well.